# if else inside window.onclick not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't recive any alert, no the page isn't cached and idkw
it should set opacity of my register form to 0 or at least show me an alert, the rest of the code works so it isn't a typo before

```js
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target.parentElement) {
        alert()
        if (!(event.target.matches(".box") || event.target.parentElement.matches(".box") || event.target.matches(".loginRegisterButtons"))) {
            registerForm.css("opacity", 0)
            registerForm.css("pointer-events", "none")
            loginForm.css("opacity", 0)
            loginForm.css("pointer-events", "none")
        }
    } else {
        alert()
        registerForm.css("opacity", 0)
        registerForm.css("pointer-events", "none")
        loginForm.css("opacity", 0)
        loginForm.css("pointer-events", "none")
    }
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target.parentElement && event.target.parentElement.parentElement && event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement && event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement && event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement) {
        alert()
        if (!(event.target.matches("#show-messages") || event.target.matches(".wrapper") || event.target.parentElement.matches(".wrapper") || event.target.parentElement.parentElement.matches(".wrapper") || event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.matches(".wrapper") || event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.matches(".wrapper") || event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.matches(".wrapper"))) {
            $(".wrapper").css("display", "none")
            $(".wrapper").css("pointer-events", "none")
        }
    } else {
        $(".wrapper").css("display", "none")
        $(".wrapper").css("pointer-events", "none")
    }
}
```

Comment: There can only be one value for `window.onclick`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than setting the click callback with `window.onclick` you should use [.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to add each listener to the window object. The way you have it the second time you set `window.onlick` it overwrites the first.

```js
window.addEventListener('click', function(event){
  if (event.target.parentElement){
    alert()
    if (!( event.target.matches(".box") || event.target.parentElement.matches(".box") || event.target.matches(".loginRegisterButtons") ) ){
      registerForm.css("opacity",  0)
      registerForm.css("pointer-events", "none")
      loginForm.css("opacity",  0)
      loginForm.css("pointer-events", "none")
  }
} else {
  alert()
  registerForm.css("opacity",  0)
  registerForm.css("pointer-events", "none")
  loginForm.css("opacity",  0)
  loginForm.css("pointer-events", "none")
}
});


window.addEventListener('click', function(event){
  if (event.target.parentElement && event.target.parentElement.parentElement && event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement && event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement && event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement){
    alert()
    if (!(event.target.matches("#show-messages") || event.target.matches(".wrapper") || event.target.parentElement.matches(".wrapper") || event.target.parentElement.parentElement.matches(".wrapper") || event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.matches(".wrapper") || event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.matches(".wrapper") || event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.matches(".wrapper"))){
      $(".wrapper").css("display", "none")
      $(".wrapper").css("pointer-events", "none")
    }
  } else {
    $(".wrapper").css("display", "none")
    $(".wrapper").css("pointer-events", "none")
  }
});
```

Comment: Or, since the OP is apparently using jQuery anyway, `$(window).on("click", ... )`

Comment: I put it all in once but i like your solution